# How to refresh List in JList

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I have a custom list class that extends AbstractList. Inside my CustomList class, there are two ArrayLists and various methods including add/remove objects methods and methods to return the two lists individually.

Now I am showing my list by the following:

```
testJList = new JList(CustomList.returnList1().toArray());
```

My returnList1() methods returns ArrayList.

But when I add an object using my CustomList method of addObject(Object o),
the list does not update.

Is there a way to update the list and use my CustomList class?

I know the object is successfully added to the list in CustomList since I made sure to print a message for success and check for errors.

Thank you so much

Comment: Swing components store the data in a "model". You need to update the `ListModel` of the `JList` when you want to change the data that is display in the JList, not an external ArrayList.

Comment: I would suggest that your custom list implements the (or returns a) `ListModel` (eventually extending `AbstractListModel`) which is then used by the `JList`. Every time the data is changed the appropriate event (see `ListDataListener` and `ListDataEvent`) must be fired.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific interface for this purpose that implements the publish subscribe pattern called [ListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) (as mentioned in the comments), providing a mechanism for the graphics components to get redrawn when needed. [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface isn't designed to provide such a mechanism. [DefaultListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) is a built-in implementation of the ListModel.

```
JList<String> myList = new JList<>();
DefaultListModel<String> myModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
myModel.addElement("My string");
myList.setModel(myModel);
myModel.addElement("Another string");
```

Comment: To my understanding, my CustomList class would then be rendered useless? Since I am now treating DefaultListModel as a list. And that all new Objects I want to create and remove will be done via the addElement/removeElement?

Comment: @Owen Your question is already answered in the comments. However, if you can't modify the CustomList class, then you may need to create a decorator which will  extend the AbstactListModel.